# Should my name be appearing when I flag a question, and it is closed?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I flagged a question as being not a real question:
[image]

But, at [the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/all-cases-when-we-are-using-the-apostrophe-like-s-or-in-ending), my username does not appear; is this a bug, or do I not have enough rep?

Answer (score 8):

This is the correct behavior. If you're under 3k rep, you can bring posts to the community's attention (it appears for 10k users and mods), but you have not yet been vested with the authority to vote to close questions. There's a reason for this—the closing process has to be understood to be a process that is entrusted to experienced site users, so until that point, your name will not be shown because you can't actually vote to close.

That said, keep flagging if you see posts that should be closed! You'll still gain flag weight, which is displayed on your profile.